# generate notifications on screen

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I wanted to ask a question you have to see if I can help. 
I've started working on a (Android) application that should display a message on the android device. This message should be Push notification type, as would be when we get a whatsapp, with the only difference that this message does not come out, but will be a sort of alarm, since the user will mark what time to leave this notice. 
And want to know what kind of message should work, and if it's with Push notifications, if they know of any conditions or any manual tutorial, because I've seen so far the only thing that has made ​​me lose more. 
Thank you.

Comment: urmmm. you want us to help you or you want to help us?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need Push Notification but AlarmManger and NotificationManager samples.

http://androidideasblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/alarmmanager-and-notificationmanager.html